# Debug COM object created by .NET app

Tags: c++, .net, com, atl

I am trying to debug an ATL COM project which is used by a .NET WinForms app but I cant set breakpoints in the ATL project, just get the empty circle with "The breakpoint will not currently be hit blah blah blah".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Project + Properties, Debug tab, tick "Enable unmanaged code debugging"